# Does tower height matter?

Tags: stronghold-kingdoms

Obviously, [the size of the tower matters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Gimignano). However, in Stronghold Kingdoms there are several tiers of castle towers to be researched, from simple wooden scaffolds to the great stone ones. Obviously, each larger tower tier is more sturdy, thus harder to destroy, and allows more archers to be stationed on the top level (from 4 on the smallest, to 25 on the great tower). But the towers also get visibly higher as they progress in size.

The walls and towers give general height advantage over the attacking archers. However, is there any range difference between tower tiers, or is that hight difference is purely cosmetic? How does it play in desktop version of Stronghold franchise?

Comment: Note: I cannot confirm nor deny whether ranges differ from combat reports, as in motion it is hard to judge distances at various angles and the sources where the arrows come from. Also, several game wikis do not offer any range specifics.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr  Towers increase range compared to walls.

While being attacked by a fairly small Siege Camp army from the NE & SW, I noticed that archers in towers on the NW & SE walls were shooting while archers on the nearby (closer) walls were not.  Lookout Tower added about 5 squares to the range. There may be a small (1 or 2 squares) range advantage with small towers over lookout.  Attack vectors made comparison between tower types difficult.  I have not researched larger towers as of yet.